# How do you share photos from Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos

I have some photos I want to share and they're on Google Photos. I want to only share them with 1 other person who has a Gmail account. I can find share on Google+ and the option is public but this isn't what I want.

Answer (score 4):

What I am understanding, you want to share some photos from Google photos with someone who doesn't have G+ account but does have Gmail (correct me if I am wrong).

In this case follow these steps ([From Google Photos Help](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6131416)):

- Go to photos.google.com.
- Place your cursor over a photo or video you want to share. Click the checkmark.
- Select any other photos you want to share.
- At the top right, click the share icon.
- choose **Get shareable link** to send someone a link.

For more information see this [Share a photo album](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1407859?hl=en).